# Add values dynamically in XML string using python

Tags: python, xml-parsing, jinja2, elementtree, python-templates

I am new in XML and stuck on some feature. My problem statement is I have a list and an XML String (structure of XML is not fixed). I have defined some identifier in my XML string (here in my case is "{some_values}") with the same name as the name of the list. I want that when my code executes, XML string can identify that list variable and the values that are present in the list will add dynamically at run time.

```
some_values=[1,2,3]
```

Input xml

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <intA>{some_values}</intA>
        </Add>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

OutPut Xml:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <intA>1</intA>
            <intA>2</intA>
            <intA>3</intA>
        </Add>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I need some approach or solution that how can I solve this problem. I read some Python XML parser's libraries and have read somewhere that we can handle XML string using python templating also but unable to find the solution that fits for this particular problem.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? As it stands, I think this is too broad/vague.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

parser = ET.XMLParser()
some_values=[1,2,3]
content='''<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <intA>{some_values}</intA>
        </Add>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
'''
tree = ET.fromstring(content, parser)
item = tree.xpath('.//*[local-name()="intA"]')
par = item[0].getparent()

for val in reversed(some_values):
    new = ET.XML(f'<intA>{val}</intA>')
    par.insert(par.index(item[0])+1,new)
par.remove(item[0])

print(etree.tostring(tree).decode())
```

Output (you can fix the formatting later):

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <intA>1</intA><intA>2</intA><intA>3</intA></Add>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```